# How to best sort a list of strings with fractions in ruby?

Tags: ruby, sorting, fractions

Take an existing list of strings with whole and fractions of inch that includes the inch symbol:

`['1"','1/2"','1 1/4"','1/4"','2"','1 1/8"']`

Is there a best (rubyish, elegant, use of methods, object oriented) way in ruby to sort so it becomes

`['1/4"','1/2"','1"','1 1/8"','1 1/4"','2"']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String#to_r`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_r) will conveniently ignore trailing garbage (such as `"`):

> The parser ignores leading whitespaces and trailing garbage.

so converting something like `'1 1/2"'` to a number that will compare sensibly is a simple matter of:

```
s = '1 1/2"'
r = s.split.map(&:to_r).inject(:+)
```

Split the string into pieces, convert each to a `Rational` using `String#to_r`, and then add them up using [`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) with a symbol argument. Clean and easy.

Once you have that, sorting is trivial:

```
array        = ['1"','1/2"','1 1/4"','1/4"','2"','1 1/8"']
rationalized = lambda { |s| s.split.map(&:to_r).inject(:+) }
sorted       = array.sort_by(&rationalized)
```

You don't have to use a lambda of course:

```
array.sort_by { |s| s.split.map(&:to_r).inject(:+) }
```

but I find that naming your little snippets of logic clarifies things.

Comment: Looks good. I agree with the use of snippets or methods to encapsulate the logic, for clarity and reusability. Thanks for the explanations and clarifying what the to_r is doing with the reference. What is the inject with the `:+` doing here for this? Is it doing the addition of the pieces after the split?

Comment: Yes, `a.inject(:+)` sums the elements of `a`: `inject` ["Combines all elements of enum by applying a binary operation, specified by a block or a symbol that names a method or operator."](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).